# Opencart 3.0 добавить глобальную переменную и свою функцию в шаблоны twig

Tags: opencart, twig

В [документации twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#globals) написано, что чтобы добавить глобальную переменную для всех шаблонов нужно:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addGlobal('text', new Text());
```

Вставить функцию:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$function = new Twig_Function('function_name', function () {
});
$twig->addFunction($function);
```

Вопрос: В какой файл в опенкарте 3.0 можно и нужно вставлять этот код, чтобы глобальные переменные работали? Или как это сделать по другому?

**Также условие**, что для переменной или функции **нужно брать данные из БД**